# Загрузка файла на сервер через AJAX

Tags: ajax, php, загрузка, fileupload

Написал загрузку файла через ajax. Всё хорошо работает, ajax возвращает нужные данные, однако файл не появляется на сервере. Думаю что проблема с правами. Как их посмотреть и поменять?

Comment: Первый и самый главный вопрос: как загружаете?

Второй вопрос: если используется какой-нить jQuery Form, то есть ли у формы атрибут enctype="multipart/form-data"?

Права на каталог можно изменить либо ФТП-клиентом, либо через SSH

Comment: Всё разобрался.

Answer (score 1):

Filezilla: Правой кнопкой мыши по файлу/папке->Права доступа к файлу

Есть прекрасный [урок](http://ruseller.com/adds.php?rub_id=12&id=1696) по загрузке файлов через ajax.

Comment: Урок не очень прекрасный, так как загрузчик выполнен на flash, а эта технология отмирает, да и тормозит к тому же. Стараюсь flash вообще не трогать.